# I installed Hyper-V Server on my computer, and it replaced Windows 8.1! I need some help getting my stuff back

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v

Like I said, I installed Hyper-V Server on my computer, and it replaced Windows 8.1. I figured out what happened and, thankfully, the install saved my old windows files into a Windows.old file, and left everything else on the disk alone. There is at least 50 GBs free on the hard drive, and I have a Windows 8.1 Pro install disk.

What I'd like to know is if Windows will automatically install to the free space, or if I have to worry about it overwriting anything already on the hard drive. In addition, should I Refresh from the additional options menu (if that's even possible??), or should I fresh install?

Thanks!

Comment: I did - I downloaded the Hyper-V 2016 Technical Preview 5 and installed it (Not realizing it would replace Windows 8!). I hadn't upgraded from 8.1 to 8.1 Pro before I installed Hyper-V.

Comment: Take a backup of all your files, which most should still be in your C:\Users\YourName folder and clean install windows 8.1